# Add a number of tables to a bookmark in Word VBA while maintaining and expanding the bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create some automation using Word VBA and looking for some advice.

I have a bookmark in a document. What I want to do is call some VBA that goes to that bookmark and creates a number of tables, could be 1, could be 50 depending on some variables.

I would like to maintain that bookmark so that it covers the entirety of that new section of tables so that if someone runs the macro again, the tables are dropped and recreated nicely.

So far I have some code that creates the tables at the bookmark and recreates it but it seems to be creating the bookmark in the first cell as the tables nest.

Can anybody help me?

```
Private Sub InsertTableInBookmark(BookmarkName As String)

Debug.Print "[INFO] Started Private Sub InsertTableInBookmark"

Dim objRng As Range
Dim objTable As Table

Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=BookmarkName
Selection.Expand wdParagraph

ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=9, NumColumns:=4, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add BookmarkName, Selection.Range

Debug.Print "[INFO] Finished Private Sub InsertTableInBookmark"

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub InsertTableInBookmark(BmkNm As String, t As Long)
Dim i As Long, BmkRng As Range, Tbl As Table
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(BmkNm) Then
    Set BmkRng = .Bookmarks(BmkNm).Range
    For i = 1 To t
      Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=BmkRng.Characters.Last, _
        NumRows:=9, NumColumns:=4, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior)
      With BmkRng
        .End = Tbl.Range.End
        If i < t Then
          .Characters.Last.Next.InsertBefore vbCr & vbCr
          .End = .End + 2
        End If
      End With
    Next
    .Bookmarks.Add BmkNm, BmkRng
  End If
End With
Set BmkRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that I've added another parameter to the sub - t - for the number of tables to insert.

Comment: Thanks @macropod. This certainly seems to get me some way there. What I'm seeing with this code is that the inserted tables seem to get the format from the H2 heading directly above the bookmark, so the tables have 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc in each cell. On second run I also see the H2 heading directly after the tables losing the first char from the title.

The structure of my document is like this:

1.1 Heading
[AUTOMATION BOOKMARK]  <----- This is the bookmark
1.2 Heading 2
Content goes here

Comment: The code does *exactly* as you asked, allowing you to input any number of tables in one go. The tables get their underlying formatting from whatever paragraph you've attached it to. Simply attach the bookmark to an empty paragraph formatted with whatever Style you want applied to the tables - or change the Style afterwards. If you're going to do a 'second run, then you need to start off by inserting two empty paras after the last bookmarked table. Study the code. Obviously, if you want to delete any existing bookmarked tables, you need to add code for that - which you didn't ask for.